# Как ускорить загрузку ифномации с бд на сайт

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица в которую выгружается информация с бд , но из за большого количества информации это происходит очень долго,  хотелось бы это как то ускорить

Сам скрипт подлкючения к бд и выгрузки с нее инфы

```
 <?php
                    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","work2");
                    $db->set_charset("utf8");
                    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM katalog");
                    $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                    if ($_r > 0)
                    {
                        while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                        {
                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[0].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[1].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[5].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[7].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[16].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[12].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[20].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[18].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[21].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[14].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[15].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[13].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[4].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                            
                            ';
                            
                            
                        }                       
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                    }

                ?>
```

Comment: Формируйте на стороне БД сразу весь HTML-текст `<tr>...</tr>`. Избавите PHP от кучи геморроя с подстановками.

Comment: @Akina, если есть возможность можно более подробно объяснить , как сформировать на стороне бд HTML

Comment: ```SELECT CONCAT('<tr><td>', CONCAT_WS('</td><td>', column0, column1, column5, ... , column13, column4), '</td></tr>') `html` FROM ...``` и соответственно просто `echo $tablerows[0];`.

Comment: у вас тут даже замена конкатенации на подстановку переменной в строку прирост скорости даст

Comment: вообще долго это сколько? вы замеряли время, требуемое именно на цикл генерации разметки? И есть ли резон выгружать все за раз? может надо первые 100 записей выдать, а остальное аяксом подгрузить.по ходу дела.

Comment: @teran долго это больше 15 минут , если есть возможно можно пример как можно это реализовать _может надо первые 100 записей выдать_

Comment: это ж сколько миллионов записей вы выгружаете? вы также зря выбираете `select *` потому что данные с БД вытягиваете, а потом используете только часть из них. А серверу БД тоже ведь требуется ресурсы и время, чтобы выбрать эти ненужные данные, а потом еще при таком объеме и передать их на сторону пхп. Дайте больше данных. опишите структуру таблицы БД. используемую версию пхп.

Comment: Как вы кстати скорост засекаете? время загрузки страницы в бразуере, или в самом коде засекаете? Браузеру тоже потребуется очень много времени на то чтобы отрендерить такой большой объем, не считает того, что ее еще от сервера получиь надо сначала целиком. А за 15 минут там явно дело в десятках мегабайт контента небось.

Comment: в общем в любом случае, при огромном объеме данных, делайте выборку только нужных полей из таблицы, сортируйте их в необходимом порядке, и для первого показа таблицы делайте в запросе `limit 0, 200` например. Для дальней подгрузки данных на странице читайте про ajax.